# How to add rules to iptables raw table?

Tags: linux, networking, security, iptables

I am working on Linux Mint 18.1 and GNU/Linux Debian 9 Stretch (testing).

I have only IPv4 available. I would like to increase security on my network, I read this: [Block Well-Known TCP Attacks](https://serverfault.com/questions/245711/iptables-tips-tricks/245713#245713). Supposing I would like to give it a try despite [this comment](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4603/tips-for-a-secure-iptables-config-to-defend-from-attacks-client-side).

The problem is, I don't know how to add these rules to `iptables`' `raw` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help from [`iptables-save`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables-save), I found out what the proper format is, when saving it to:

```
/etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

Sample of the rules on the link in the question follows:

```
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -p icmp -m u32 ! --u32 "0x4&0x3fff=0x0" -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p icmp -m length --length 1492:65535 -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,PSH,URG -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG -j DROP
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I assume you don't care about IPv6. So the file you want to edit is:

```
/etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

Put this at the top of your iptables file. It is a skeleton implementation of the RAW table, which is used before any table associated with routing (such as FILTER). Note that each table has its own COMMIT command at the bottom of its definitions:

```
*raw
:TCPFLAGS - [0:0]

# the two rules below assure that only TCP packets get examined. All others continue into the *filter table.
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -j TCPFLAGS
-A PREROUTING -j ACCEPT

# quickly accept standard handshakes
# ALLOW ACK or ACK/SYN
#-A TCPFLAGS -j ACCEPT
-A TCPFLAGS -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,ACK,URG,PSH,RST ACK  -j ACCEPT

# allow ACK/FIN with either URG or PSH, or both, or neither
# but SYN and RST can't be set
-A TCPFLAGS -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,ACK,RST  ACK,FIN -j ACCEPT

# allow SYN or ACK/SYN
-A TCPFLAGS -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,URG,PSH,RST SYN -j ACCEPT

# allow RST or ACK/RST
-A TCPFLAGS -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,URG,PSH,RST RST -j ACCEPT

# this rule catches xmas-tree and fin attacks
-A TCPFLAGS -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN     FIN     -j DROP

# this rule catches xmas-tree and syn/rst attacks
-A TCPFLAGS -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN     SYN     -j DROP

# this rule catches null attacks
-A TCPFLAGS -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL     NONE    -j DROP

#-A TCPFLAGS -p tcp -ecn-tcp-cwr -j DROP
# these rules catch bad ack combinations
#-A TCPFLAGS -p tcp --tcp-flags ACK     ACK     -j ACC
-A TCPFLAGS -j ACCEPT

# so, what do we accept for tcp?
# handshakes (ACK/FIN), (ACK/SYN), (SYN), (ACK), (RST), (ACK/RST), and data packets with 
# PSH or URG or FIN or ACK

COMMIT
```

The above sits above the *filter definitions. I make no claims as to the correctness of the rules. Note that I've commented out some rules that didn't work for me. If you find anything wrong with my rules, please put it below.